# Replacing multiple fdatasync() calls with a single sync() call

Tags: linux, kernel, fsync, durability

I have an application with thousands of files being updated. Periodically the application needs to commit the changes to the disk, and currently I am calling `fdatasync()`, which takes significant amount of time (minutes). [Reducing the number of files being written is not an option for me.]

At the same time, I noticed that if I ran the `sync` command from the command line, it would return significantly faster. From the documentation it seems like it would guarantee that all pending writes reached the disk.

The question is: does the `sync()` system call give the same (or stronger) durability guarantees as multiple `fdatasync()` calls? If not, is there a way to `fsync()` multiple file descriptors in one call?

Comment: `strace` `sync` command and see what it does.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `strace` does not show what happens inside a syscall, and all that `sync` command does is calling the `sync` syscall. My question is if `sync` syscall is as good as `fdatasync` in a scope of several open file descriptors.

Comment: So your question is essentially `fdatasync()` vs `sync()`.

Comment: Yes, updated the question to be more clear.